# Pageant - reports error "can't open file" but loads keys anyway

Tags: ssh, powershell, putty, pageant

I'm using Pageant 0.70 to load keys on Windows 10 via a PowerShell script:

**profile-file.ps1**

```
$pageant-path = "c:\full-path-to-pageant.exe"
$keypath1 = c:\full-path-to-key1
$keypath2 = c:\full-path-to-key2
$keypath3 = c:\full-path-to-key3
```

**init.ps1**

```
# sourcing from profile
. profile-file.ps1

# load keys - doing this because keys are in different locations and paths are too long to have in one spot
& $pageantpath -a "$keypath1"
& $pageantpath -a "$keypath2"
& $pageantpath -a "$keypath3"
```

When the Pageant commands in `init.ps1` run, for each one I get the error popup

> couldn't open this key (unable to open file")

But when I check Pageant after clearing the popups, the keys are all successfully loaded in Pageant and I can use them.

I've tried

1. Wrapping key in quotes
2. Using the `-c` flag on Pageant to run a command
3. Running from command line
4. Using/not using `-a` Pageant command line switch

So far, all of these are having the same result - I get error popups but the keys load. Any other approaches I can use to prevent these error popups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c:\full-path-to-pageant.exe -a c:\full-path-to-key1
```

Pageant does not have any `-a` switch. It takes the `-a` as a file name and tries to load it, failing. Hence the error message. Then it takes the next argument and successfully loads that key.

Comment: I dropped the -a and it seems to load fine. Thanks for the tip.